# How to specify number of target classes for TFRobertaSequenceClassification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I have a text classification task at hand and I want to use RoBERTa pre-trained model from the `transformers` python library.

As per the documentation of [TFRobertaForSequenceClassification](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/roberta.html#transformers.TFRobertaForSequenceClassification) to train we have to use,

```
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer, TFRobertaForSequenceClassification

tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
model = TFRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('roberta-base')

model.compile('adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(x, y)
```

So where should I specify the number of target labels for sequence classification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `num_labels` parameter.

```
model = TFRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('roberta-base', num_labels = 5)
```

ref: https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/configuration.html

Comment: Is it possible to set  a dropout rate? The classification head of `TFRobertaForSequenceClassification` has a dropout layer? I'm wondering how to pass a dropout rate